# Detecting bad AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What are some of the common practices in detecting bad instances in a large cluster of instances.

Example of a bad instance: Instance has very high CPU usage when compared to other instances in the cluster, though the amount of work (number of HTTP requests processed) done by the instance is almost same as the work done by other instances.

Comment: Are you talking about IO issues? Amazon guarantee you CPU and memory amounts as per the instance you choose. EBS and local disk performance is another matter.

Comment: There have been rare instances of excessive processor queuing with AWS instances, which would potentially create symptoms like you describe, but in general instances do not just "Go Bad". It is always possible that something goes wrong on the hardware level for a given instance, but again this is rare and symptoms would vary widely.

Comment: @CIGuy you are right in that these instances didn't "go bad". They were bad from the time they were spun up. When you are dealing with a huge cluster there is a very chance you will have some of these. I was thinking of libraries which would detect these and relaunch the instance. I guess relaunching gives you a new instance.

Comment: Have you seen the Netflix Janitor Monkey? It is designed to detect and terminate unused instances, but it uses a set of rules which can be extended so you could potentially create a rule set to detect your bad instances. https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Janitor-Home

Comment: Also, if you terminate an instance it cannot be "Relaunched". You can create a new instance of course, which would be separate from the bad instance except that perhaps you used the same base AMI.